# DeserializeObject with Newtonsoft list in a list

Tags: c#, .net, json, winforms

First off, sorry for my bad English. Hi there, I am trying to deserialize json (with newtonsoft) to a list, which works great. But my only problem is that I need to put a list inside a list, if this is even possible. Why I want to do this is because I have a set of items with subitems in it. How do I put all of them in a nice sorted list? Here is some example code I made:

**C# Code**

```
var items = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Items>>(wc.DownloadString("http://localhost/index.php"));
foreach (var item in items)
{
    Console.WriteLine(item);
}

listItems.AddRange(items);

public class Items
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Genre { get; set; }
    public string Size { get; set; }
    public string Version { get; set; }
    public string Download_Link { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

**JSON**

```
[
    {
        "id": "1",
        "name": "Application 1",
        "genre": "Something",
        "description": "The description",
        "versions": [
            {
                "appid": "1",
                "version": "1",
                "patch_notes": "Release version.",
                "download_link": "http://localhost/downloads/application_1.zip",
                "size": 5120
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

My problem is that I can't seem to put the second array inside of the list with the items. I know I'm doing something wrong, but I can't seem to figure out what, could someone please help me with this? It would be very appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the json, Versions is an array.  You'll have to model that object as well.

Your model should look something like this

```
public class Items
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Genre { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public List<Version> Versions { get; set; }
}

public class Version
{
    public string Appid { get; set; }
    public string Version { get; set; }
    public string Patch_Notes { get; set; }
    public string Download_Link { get; set; }
    public int Size { get; set; }
}
```